# ¿Como puedo arreglar un problema al momento de importar las librerías de Sunpy?

Tags: python

¡Hola! estimada comunidad de Stack Over Flow estoy tratando de correr los siguientes códigos de la librería de Sunpy en Spyder.

```
from sunpy.net import Fido
from sunpy.net import attrs as a
from sunpy.timeseries import TimeSeries
```

Desafortunadamente en la terminal me sale este mensaje largo.

```
runfile('C:/Users/USER/.spyder-py3/temp.py', wdir='C:/Users/USER/.spyder-py3')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\py3compat.py:356 in compat_exec
    exec(code, globals, locals)

  File c:\users\user\.spyder-py3\temp.py:8
    from sunpy.net import Fido

  File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sunpy\net\__init__.py:8
    from sunpy.net import jsoc as _

  File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sunpy\net\jsoc\__init__.py:1
    from sunpy.net.jsoc.attrs import *

  File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sunpy\net\jsoc\attrs.py:3
    from sunpy.coordinates.utils import get_rectangle_coordinates

  File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sunpy\coordinates\__init__.py:21
    from . import sun

  File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sunpy\coordinates\sun.py:34
    from .transformations import _SOLAR_NORTH_POLE_HCRS, _SUN_DETILT_MATRIX

  File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sunpy\coordinates\transformations.py:647
    _SUN_DETILT_MATRIX = _rotation_matrix_reprs_to_reprs(_SOLAR_NORTH_POLE_HCRS,

  File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sunpy\coordinates\transformations.py:597 in 
  _rotation_matrix_reprs_to_reprs
    rotation_axis = A.cross(B)

  File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\astropy\coordinates\representation.py:1513 in 
    cross
    other_c.get_xyz(xyz_axis=-1))

  File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\astropy\coordinates\representation.py:1351 in 
 get_xyz
   return np.stack([self._x, self._y, self._z], axis=xyz_axis)

  File <__array_function__ internals>:200 in stack

  File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\astropy\units\quantity.py:1683 in 
 __array_function__
    return super().__array_function__(function, types, args, kwargs)

  File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\shape_base.py:471 in stack
    return _nx.concatenate(expanded_arrays, axis=axis, out=out,

  File <__array_function__ internals>:200 in concatenate

  File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\astropy\units\quantity.py:1688 in 
__array_function__
args, kwargs, unit, out = function_helper(*args, **kwargs)

TypeError: concatenate() got an unexpected keyword argument 'dtype'
```

¿Que podría estar pasando?

Comment: El error viene causado porque astropy (dependencia de sunpy) intenta llamar a `numpy.concatenate` con el argumento `dtype`. El argumento `dtype` se agrego a `NumPy` en la version 1.20, sospecho que tienes instalado `NumPy <= 1.19`. ¿Has probado a realizar la instalacion en limpio en un nuevo entrono virtual?

Comment: @FJSevilla tengo la versión 1.24.3 de NumPy

Comment: @FJSevilla, no he hecho la instalación en un entorno virtual

Comment: Vale, y que version de pysun y astropy tienes instaladas?

Comment: @FJSevilla de astropy tengo la versión 5.1 y de sunpy 5.0.1

Comment: Están  desactualizados especialmente astropy, esa version es de 2022 (version mas nueva es la 6.0).  Anaconda parece que dispone de una versión demasiado antigua de astropy,... Actualiza ambos paquetes, especialmente astropy, no uso conda, pero [conda-forge](https://conda-forge.org/docs/) si ofrece versiones actualizadas: `conda update -c conda-forge astropy`, otra opcion es instalar desde PyPi con pip.

Comment: @FJSevilla, ya actualize el astropy, pero sigue el mismo error